# How to find the sum of all the elements in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, sum, double

I need to find the sum of all the elements in my 2D Array but the elements are doubles and they're only being added as integers. The output is coming out as `55` when it should come out as `59.6`. Any form of help is greatly appreciated.

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] step4 =
                {{1.1,2.2},{3.3,4.4},{5.5,6.6},{7.7,8.8},{9.9,10.10}};
        int sum = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < step4.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < step4[r].length; c++) {
                sum += step4[r][c];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: int sum = 0;, make this double or something that can store more precision, and fractional values.

Comment: if you want a `double` result,  then sum them up in a `double`-variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your sum variable from int to double. Because you are doing addition with doubles and in the end you cast them to int.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I'm new to this and don't really know the features yet

Answer (score 0):

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] step4 =
                {{1.1,2.2},{3.3,4.4},{5.5,6.6},{7.7,8.8},{9.9,10.10}};
        double sum = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < step4.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < step4[r].length; c++) {
                sum += step4[r][c];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Here is the output]

Comment: Code-only anwers are diiscouraged. We should rather explain the problem(s) and how our solution fixes it (them).

Comment: I got it bro :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DoubleStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html) for this purpose:

```java
double[][] arr = {{1.1,2.2},{3.3,4.4},{5.5,6.6},{7.7,8.8},{9.9,10.10}};

double sum = Arrays.stream(arr).flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream).sum();

System.out.println(sum); // 59.6
```